# What is this panel on my ceiling? How can it be opened?

Tags: ceiling

This panel is in our bedroom closet in our apartment.

We're not sure what it is, or how to open it.

Is it for storage? The sprinkler system? A gateway to Narnia?

Can anyone give us any insight?

[image: panel]

Comment: What's above your apartment?

Comment: is it not obvious that a key is required?

Comment: Probably just attic access. There may also be HVAC equipment there that needs to  be serviced regularly.

Comment: It is probably maintenance access to the plumbing and electrical for the building and that is why it is locked.

Comment: That is where the landlord stashed the Lil' Bits of the last tenant that asked to many questions.

Comment: Is your apartment on the top floor?

Comment: My apartment is on the top floor, yes. We have vaulted ceilings. I'm going to ask my front office tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 4):

It is the access panel to the opening to access the attic space above your ceiling.  It has a key lock that the Apt manager or maintenance staff has a key to.